# Ubuntu 20.04 - I Do Not Get Logged In Properly After Nvidia Driver Update

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, graphics, microphone

I have an "HP ZBook" laptop.

It is a **dual boot** device with:

1. Windows 10
2. Ubuntu 20.04

It also has two GPUs:

1. NVIDIA Quadro P600 Mobile
2. Intel UHD Graphics 630 Mobile

This is the output of `lspci | grep VGA`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GLM [Quadro P600 Mobile] (rev a1)
```

Yesterday both [Alacritty](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty) and [Kitty](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/) (terminal emulators) stopped working. They encountered an error with "OpenGL 3.3 drivers". When I searched online I found people saying that the graphics card drivers got updated and I just need to reboot for everything to work. I rebooted, Ubuntu did not open up. It stayed on the boot screen (the one with the Ubuntu logo). After trying many commands that I found online and do not understand, it got back to boot properly.

The problem now is whenever I login, Ubuntu asks me for the password three more times (after the initial one):

[image: Authentication required to create a color managed device]
[image: Authentication required to create a color profile]
[image: Authentication required to refresh system repositories]

Also, when I try to shutdown, or reboot the device, it asks me for a password. It also says that other users are logged in, even though I am using the only logged in account.

[image: Other users are logged in]

Also, the microphone stopped getting recognized. So for example when I open Zoom in Chrome it says that the microphone is not detected. I don't know how it is related, but it was working fine before all of this happens.

In the Software and Update in Ubuntu, it says that the NVIDIA driver is fine:

[image: NVIDIA driver working]

However, when I run `nvidia-smi` I get:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

I don't know what is going on but seems like everything went crazy. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try disabling Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: @Terrance I do not have that option in the BIOS. I searched online and it seems like devices who don't have the option don't support it in the first place...

Comment: Usually blocked NVIDIA drivers are because of Secure Boot.  You can try running `prime-select query` and see what it is set for either intel or nvidia.  I would also consult HP because searches that I am looking up others are asking about how to disable Secure Boot for the ZBooks.  And sometimes, I have seen Secure Boot named different things where you have to remove the Keys in order for it to disable it.